# Display a full image in css

Tags: html, css

I was working on a project last three months and I stopped for something else, now Im back to continue and Im facing a problem.

Before I start explain my problem, I would invite you to run this snippet so that you will understand more my problem:

```css
/***************Style.css**************/

/* Circular Content Carousel Style */
.ca-container{
 position:relative;
 margin:25px auto 20px auto;
 width:1200px;
 height:700px;
}
.ca-wrapper{
 width: 1200px;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
.ca-item{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:330px;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
.ca-item-main{
 position:absolute;
 right:80px;
 bottom:5px;
 background:#fff;
 overflow:hidden;
 width: 325px;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.ca-nav span{
 width:25px;
 height:38px;
 background:transparent url(https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AADIMMteRhEB2NiHzX_Z0MquXnxppt4ivpdmarz52rDyOQ/12/226666032/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/arrows.png/EO2pmKoBGH0gAigC/aALpyYLbAaADO2-Ebio68A3s-L7ioYLKSv_9ocokcRY?size=1024x768&size_mode=3) no-repeat top left;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-19px;
 left:-40px;
 text-indent:-9000px;
 opacity:0.7;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:100;
}
.ca-nav span.ca-nav-next{
 background-position:top right;
 left:auto;
 right:-40px;
}
.ca-nav span:hover{
 opacity:1.0;
}

/**********Demo.cs*****************/


@import url('reset.css');

/* General Demo Style */
body{
 background:#e4ebe9 url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
 color:#000;
 font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
}
a{
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.clr{
 clear:both;
}
h1, h5{
 margin:15px;
 font-size:44px;
 color:#000;
 font-family: 'Rochester', sans-serif;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
 text-align:center;
}
h1 span, h5{
 font-size:20px;
 display:block;
 color:#60817a;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Circular Content Carousel with jQuery" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, conent slider, content carousel, circular, expanding, sliding, css3" />
  <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" media="all" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow&v1' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coustard:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    </head>
    <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
    <div class="ca-wrapper">
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AABfvRL8isymJa1pWpA-ta-oyC1pyOUPWec4nRnWS_SiHA/12/226666032/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/3.jpg/EO2pmKoBGHwgAigC/iV0gUV38M-Y4EoQJWevkk6_etV3EZi1baTQUzImrReM?size=1024x768&size_mode=3"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AABfvRL8isymJa1pWpA-ta-oyC1pyOUPWec4nRnWS_SiHA/12/226666032/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/3.jpg/EO2pmKoBGHwgAigC/iV0gUV38M-Y4EoQJWevkk6_etV3EZi1baTQUzImrReM?size=1024x768&size_mode=3"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AABfvRL8isymJa1pWpA-ta-oyC1pyOUPWec4nRnWS_SiHA/12/226666032/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/3.jpg/EO2pmKoBGHwgAigC/iV0gUV38M-Y4EoQJWevkk6_etV3EZi1baTQUzImrReM?size=1024x768&size_mode=3"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

After running the snippet, you will see three blocs, the image in each bloc has a size of 380x650. I would like to display the entire image in the bloc but Im unable, Whenever I try, the size of the image which will be displayed is 375x650, instead of 380x650.
I have been playing around with the value but no amelioration.

Please let me know how to fix this problem.

Sorry for the english, Im not a native english speaker, Im trying my best

Comment: Your images not loaded for me, I updated your example with new image, and didn't see any problem, please see this and let me know whats the problem exactly? [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/9ezu54pk/)

Comment: Thanks for providing your help. Normally ".ca-item-main" must have a width of 380px but when I set this value, Im unable to apply a margin-right to get a space between each bloc (just as in your demo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now with `width: 380px;` and looks ok.

```css
/***************Style.css**************/
.ca-item-main .wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
}
/* Circular Content Carousel Style */
.ca-container{
 position:relative;
 margin:25px auto 20px auto;
 width:1200px;
 height:700px;
}
.ca-wrapper{
 width: 1200px;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
.ca-item{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:380px;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
      margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
.ca-item-main{
 position:absolute;
 right:80px;
 bottom:5px;
 background:#fff;
 overflow:hidden;
 width: 380px;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.ca-nav span{
 width:25px;
 height:38px;
 background:transparent url(https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AADIMMteRhEB2NiHzX_Z0MquXnxppt4ivpdmarz52rDyOQ/12/226666032/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/arrows.png/EO2pmKoBGH0gAigC/aALpyYLbAaADO2-Ebio68A3s-L7ioYLKSv_9ocokcRY?size=1024x768&size_mode=3) no-repeat top left;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-19px;
 left:-40px;
 text-indent:-9000px;
 opacity:0.7;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:100;
}
.ca-nav span.ca-nav-next{
 background-position:top right;
 left:auto;
 right:-40px;
}
.ca-nav span:hover{
 opacity:1.0;
}

/**********Demo.cs*****************/


@import url('reset.css');

/* General Demo Style */
body{
 background:#e4ebe9 url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
 color:#000;
 font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
}
a{
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.clr{
 clear:both;
}
h1, h5{
 margin:15px;
 font-size:44px;
 color:#000;
 font-family: 'Rochester', sans-serif;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
 text-align:center;
}
h1 span, h5{
 font-size:20px;
 display:block;
 color:#60817a;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
    <div class="ca-wrapper">
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/lockbox.png"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/lockbox.png"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/lockbox.png"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @jiff, It is looking ok. please can I get the points where you applied your modifications ?

Comment: I set `width: 380px;` for `.ca-item` and `.ca-item-main` then set margin. and also set `width: 100%` for `.ca-item-main .wrapper img`. your welcome, please accept answer.

Comment: Thanks. Hope I can contact you if I need your help.

Comment: Sure, I'm here and if you need help please let me know.

Comment: Im inviting you to check my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272568/add-touch-swipe-slide-effet-to-circular-content-carousel/

I have been struggling the past two days but no result.