# Add touch swipe slide effet to circular content carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this great thumb slider http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/

However it doesn't offer swipe support for touch based devices. Is there any way to add touch-swipe support to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the jQuery.contentcarousel.js code in the section labeled "init", you can see where it sets the function bindings to the elements for ca-nav-prev and ca-nav-next (the classes defined in the CSS for the nav buttons):

```
var $navPrev        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
    $navNext        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-next');
```

...

A little further down in the code you can see where it binds the click events for these objects to do the nav:

```
        // navigate left
        $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                cache.isAnimating   = true;
                aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
        });

        // navigate right
        $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                cache.isAnimating   = true;
                aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
        });
```

All you need to do to enable swipe support is to replace this event binding logic which ties to the buttons with a swipe event (would recommend binding to a swipe event on ca-container which holds the carousel) like so:

```
// Swipe left, advance carousel to right
$wrapper.on('swipeleft',function(event){
    if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
    cache.isAnimating   = true;
    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
});
// Swipe right, advance carousel to left
$wrapper.on('swiperight',function(event){
    if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
    cache.isAnimating   = true;
    aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
});
```

To make use of jQuery mobile gestures, you will need to include the following in the  section of your HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
```

According to the jQuery mobile documentation, mobile only works with jQuery 1.8 and newer, so you should up-version the jQuery referenced in the HTML source since they're using an older version (1.6.2):

http://api.jquerymobile.com

Here for instance is an example from W3:

[Example from W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_events_swipeleft)

So you likely need to replace the jQuery reference in the HTML file with a newer version for jQuery mobile support, e.g.:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Note: the code originally referenced is using an older version of jQuery.  In updating jQuery to the newer version needed for jQuery mobile, the original code breaks on deprecated calls to ".live(event, handler)".  These deprecated calls need to be updated with preferred ".on(event, handler)" event bindings for newer versions of jQuery.  I was able to get swipe events to navigate correctly with modifications as noted after commenting out deprecated references.

Comment: Thanks for providing your help but it does not work when I replaced the part concerning the nav right and left by the code you just provided.
Or Im maybe messing everything up because of my very limited knowledge in jquery

Comment: Since they're already defining a wrapper var I changed code slightly in answer.  What browser/device are you using to test?  Also probably forgot to mention that you need jQuery mobile - will add that to answer.

Comment: ...and swap out the version of jQuery referenced since the jQuery version is older than what is supported in jQuery Mobile.  Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks one more time, but anytime I try to make a change, the slider stops working, either nothing appears or the nav buttons do not perfom any action.

As Im not able to run my modifed code source on this site, I just uploaded my .zip file on my dropbox, so that you can have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0pgyk8mbplgih0/carousel.zip?dl=0

Comment: Okay - one more change you have to make when updating to newer jQuery.  The "live" event in contentcarousel.js has been deprecated so this breaks when changing to new jQuery (required for jQuery mobile swipe events).  Since you're not using those methods right now, I just commented out the "open" and "close" event definitions - those need to be replaced with "on" bindings since "live" has been deprecated.  After making that change in your code (on top of adding newer jQuery, with reference to jQuery mobile immediately following), it works for me now to advance left / right with swipe.

Comment: You are very kind, you have been providing your help since the beginning. Thanks for everything.

I have tried it again but the same thing, what I am going to ask will seem crazy but can you upload a .zip file where you made your changes( with comments in the file) so that I will easily understand what is going on.

Thanks one more time

Comment: Here's my modified version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ctesfh3sdnlcbg/carousel.zip?dl=0

Comment: Only the ajax loader icon appears when Im running the index.html

Comment: Code is working for me with swipe gestures on Safari (from local file).  Also loaded on my home web server and confirmed it works from iPhone, iPad, and Macbook pro with left and right swipe gestures.  Not sure I can provide any further help.  If you've got Safari you can enable Develop mode and debug to make sure the assets are all loading correctly.

Comment: I just tried the .zip file in Safari and it is working correctly apart form the next/prev buttons which  are not working. I think on apple devices the codes are ok.

Comment: I deactivated the LR buttons while testing, but you can turn them back on by uncommenting the corresponding code in the JavaScript file.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested the project on firefox, opera, chrome and safari. It works only on firefox and safari

Comment: Here is a link to jQuery mobile platform support documentation.  I'll leave the troubleshooting of issues on specific platforms as an exercise for the reader :-).  As stated on this page, jQuery mobile is broadly-supported, which I believe makes its use the preferred approach (others are welcome to present alternate solutions as additional answers).

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0b1/docs/about/platforms.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the help you have been providing. ;)